# Is there a solution to my problem in laravel and visual studio code

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code

I have a problem.

We are currently creating a login and registration system using laravel and visual studio code but when I debug or when I add code like style I put background-image or color but my problem is that it doesn't appear when I preview my project on browser and when I try to inspect it, the code is still the same and it's not changing even if I change it already in visual studio code.

What is the solution?

Comment: if you're writing plain CSS, try saving the file ctrl+s and hard refresh the browser ctrl+shift+r

Comment: Your views/styles could be cached, depending on how you are testing your project, you could do a hard refresh, as Sally suggests, or look up the artisan commands for clearing cache (if you are using artisan serve)

Comment: If you're modifying the SASS files or have CSS files in `resources` folder, you need to recompile `npm run dev`